# JPA persist not writing to database

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I'm just trying to get to know JSF and JPA but whenever I try to persist an object into the database it seems to not write away.
Here's the code I'm using:

```
@Named
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class BestemmingController implements Serializable{

@PersistenceUnit(unitName="RealDolmenTravelShopPU")
@PersistenceContext(unitName="RealDolmenTravelShopPU")

EntityManagerFactory emf = null;
public void submit(){


        try{
            emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("RealDolmenTravelShopPU");

            EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

            //EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();
            //et.begin();

            Bestemming nieuweBestemming = new Bestemming();

            Land gezochtLand = em.find(Land.class, selectedLand);

            nieuweBestemming.setLand(gezochtLand);
            nieuweBestemming.setNaam(bestemmingNaam);

            em.persist(nieuweBestemming);

            //et.commit();
            //em.flush();
            em.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            emf.close();
        }
    }
```

I tried using the EntityTransaction but it just stopped my application, without any errors or anything. So I left it out, but still it didn't write away.
So then I tried calling flush seperately, but that didn't do anything either.
I'm really stumped as to why this isn't working. It's probably some newbie mistake, but I would love it if someone here could help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unless using a JPA implementation that allows nontransactional writes (e.g DataNucleus JPA) then you will have to have a transaction to get data written to the datastore (as per the JPA spec). Address what is your error using that route

Comment: @DataNucleus I tried putting the transaction back in again, also tried echoing some text back to my page using this: `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"abcd", "dcba"));` 
When I leave out the transaction it displays the message otherwise not...

Comment: show your persistence.xml, what JPA impl do you use?

Comment: @xeye this is my persistence.xml:`<persistence-unit name="RealDolmenTravelShopPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>realdolmentravel</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, are you able to write to the logs?  Starting a transaction when specifying the persistence unit uses JTA will throw an exception, so it is likely you have just been missing exceptions in your container log files.

Second, this is a JTA PU, so it needs a JTA transaction started that the EM gets associated to, and you will want to inject the em rather than create a factory yourself.  Check out the JPA application server examples here first to see how they are set up: 
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA

Comment: Yeah I just found out myself and I was going to post it here. I set the JTA to RESOURCE_LOCAL, it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I found out why it was that the transaction wasn't running: the implementation I used didn't use JTA, it used a RESOURCE_LOCAL persistence unit. That was something I just looked over when I set up my project.

Good thing my buddy told me to check the server logs.